# Qt QML Camera shows a white screen after deployment

Tags: android, c++, qt, qml

I'm trying to build and deploy [declarative-camera](https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt5-5.11/qtmultimedia-multimedia-declarative-camera-example.html) example on my android phone but I keep receiving this error and a white screen:

> [SurfaceTexture-0-31406-1] bindTextureImage: clearing GL error: 0x502

Although when I touch the screen it appears for less than a second then turns to white screen again. I'm using `Qt 5.14/ NDK Version 20/ SDK Version 26.1.1`.

I use `QuickWidget` inside my `.cpp` file for displaying the `.qml` file by `setSource(QUrl("qrc:/declarative-camera.qml"))`.

My current Kit is **Android for armeabi-v7a,arm64-v8a,x86,x86_64 (Clang Qt 5.14.0 for Android)**. Same code used to compile successfully without any errors on the same phone with `Qt 5.13` with **Android for arm64-v8a (Clang Qt 5.13.1 for Android ARM64-v8a)** Kit.

Any idea what is causing this behavior?

P.S This is my Application Output after I call `setSource` :

> D ViewRootImpl@30773d6[QtActivity]: ViewPostIme pointer 1
>
> D InputMethodManager: HSIFW - flag : 0 Pid : 15832
>
> D InputMethodManager: HSIFW - flag : 0 Pid : 15832
>
> D SensorManager: registerListener :: 1, K6DS3TR Acceleration Sensor,
>   200000, 0,
>
> D SensorManager: unregisterListener ::
>
> D Camera  : app passed NULL surface
>
> D Camera  : app passed NULL surface
>
> D SensorManager: registerListener :: 1, K6DS3TR Acceleration Sensor,
>   200000, 0,
>
> W GLConsumer: [SurfaceTexture-0-15832-1] bindTextureImage: clearing GL
>   error: 0x502
>
> W GLConsumer: [SurfaceTexture-0-15832-1] bindTextureImage: clearing GL
>   error: 0x502

Comment: Ca you provide your Android log?

Comment: @folibis I have edited the question and added the log

Comment: I have the same. There's nothing concrete in the bugtracker, but I'm fairly sure it is a QT bug. The closest I've found is this https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-48567 - The video filter provided in the `qt3d-camera-test.zip` attachment has fixed it for me.

Comment: @gwillz it is indeed a Qt bug. after I upgraded to Qt 5.15.0 the issue is fixed (make sure to update all the components). maybe you can do the same instead of using a filer.

Comment: Yeah funny I just found the right bug report. https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-81006. It's also fixed in 5.14.2 which is due in March.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a QT bug, although it's already fixed in 5.14.2 which is due in March.

https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-81006

Comment: I know you've fixed it yourself, I've just recorded it as an answer for those looking for quick solutions.